# google-assistant-demo command not found

Tags: google-api, raspberry-pi3, google-assistant-sdk

I tried to install the Google Assistant onto my new Raspberry Pi. I watched and followed the instruction online (Google developer). I have done exactly what the instruction says. However, at the end, I typed 'google-assistant-demo' to run it. The console answered: 'command not found'
I tried to find the solution online, but I could not find any suitable solution for this situation.
Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The online instructions create a virtual python environment to keep the dependencies required by the assistant in a separate location.

Try activating the virtual environment before running this command. Here's how to -

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ source env/bin/activate
(env) pi@raspberrypi:~ $ google-assistant-demo
```

Comment: do you have a link for the instructions you followed?

Comment: I literally figured out this problem.  I had to re-enter my verification code. however, there is still one problem where the GA does not meet respond to my question, even though it recognize my voice